# Wrong scipy fit even with good initial guess

Tags: python, curve-fitting

The model to fit is the equation

```
def func(x, b):
   return b*np.exp(-b*x)*(1.0 + b*x)/4.0
```

I know that `b=0.1` is a good guess to my data

```
0 0.1932332495855138
1 0.0283534527253836
2 0.0188036856033853
3 0.0567007258167565
4 0.0704161703188139
5 0.0276463443409273
6 0.0144509808494943
7 0.0188027609145469
8 0.0049573500626925
9 0.0064589075683206
10 0.0118522499082115
11 0.0087201376939245
12 0.0055855004231049
13 0.0110355379801288
14 0.0024829496736532
15 0.0050982312687186
16 0.0041032075307342
17 0.0063991465281368
18 0.0047195530453669
19 0.0028479431829209
20 0.0177577032522473
21 0.0082863863356967
22 0.0057720347102372
23 0.0053694769677398
24 0.017408417311084
25 0.0023307847797263
26 0.0014090741613788
27 0.0019007144648791
28 0.0043599058193019
29 0.004435997067249
30 0.0015569027316533
31 0.0016127575928092
32 0.00120222948697
33 0.0006851723909766
34 0.0014497504163
35 0.0014245210449107
36 0.0011375555693977
37 0.0007939973846594
38 0.0005707034948325
39 0.0007890519641431
40 0.0006274139241806
41 0.0005899624312505
42 0.0003989619799181
43 0.0002212632688891
44 0.0001465605806698
45 0.000188075040325
46 0.0002779076010181
47 0.0002941294723591
48 0.0001690581072228
49 0.0001448055157076
50 0.0002734759385405
51 0.0003228484365634
52 0.0002120441778252
53 0.0002383276583408
54 0.0002156310534404
55 0.0004499244488764
56 0.0001408465706883
57 0.000135998586104
58 0.00028706917157
59 0.0001788548683777
```

But it doesn't matter if I set `p0=0.1`, or `p0=1.0`, the fitting parameter in both cases python says to be `popt= [0.42992594]` and `popt=[0.42994105]`, which is almost the same value. Why the `curve_fit` function doesn't work in this case?

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0=[0.1])
```

Comment: What are `pvals, pav`?

Comment: Oops, I should have written `xdata,ydata`, these are the two columns that I attached to the question.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing too mysterious going on here. 0.4299... is just a better fit to the data, in the least-squares sense.

With `b = 0.1`, the first few points are not well fit at all. Least-squares heavily weights outliers, so the optimizer tries very hard to fit those better, even if it means doing slightly worse at other points. In other words, "most" points are fit "pretty well", and there is a very high penalty for fitting any point very badly (that's the "square" in least-squares).

Below is a plot of the data (blue) and your model function with `b = 0.1` and `b = 0.4299` in orange and green respectively. The value returned by `curve_fit` is better subjectively *and* objectively. Computing the MSE to the data in both cases gives about 0.18 using `b = 0.1`, and 0.13 using `b = 0.4299`.

[image: Data vs model with various parameters]

Comment: My problem is the tail. If you look the plot in semilog scale, one gets an awful fit for tail values. Surprisingly, `exp(-Bx)` fits much better the whole curve. This is where I get $b=0.1$. I'm still confused, since the fit given in the question should be a better estimate for the empirical data, and I am expecting `B~b` (these are theoretical details involved in my particular model).

Comment: I think looking it on a semi-log scale is misleading. That will amplify differences at the smallest values. While they may appear visually large, they will contribute almost nothing to the total error during optimization. If you have reason to expect that a certain value is "better", you might try providing this as a prior, in the form of an additional term penalizing values different from your expectation.

Comment: But the first few values in the data array will definitely dominate the error metric, since they are much larger in amplitude than those at the end. As an example, an error of 10% in the first data point is 0.02, which is then squared to 4e-4. An error of 10% at the last value contributes to the total MSE about 1e-8. So the same relative error in an estimate of the first point is _four orders of magnitude_ more "important" in the optimization.

Comment: @user2820579 The question is, what is your objective and where does the data come from. If you actually asking for the long term exponential decay you may be better of fitting the log of your data. Especially if you are expecting systematic errors etc to mess up the early data. You may also rethink the chi^2 and how to handle "outliers": https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html